# How do I run multiple sleep commands for different processes in a script?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, scripting

I want to run multiple processes at the same time, on the same script with independent sleep commands on them. I've tried making different scripts and run them with a master script but the sleep command just doesn't work as I wanted it to.

I'm using while loops.

For example:

> Process A shows something at X time.
>
> Process B shows something at Y time.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; update your question w/ some code examples of what you tried

Answer (score -1):

Like mentioned in comments, somewhat vague question

Anyway, running subshells in background is one way to to run content independently of each other:

```
(
    sleep 0.5 # note: fractional sleep gnu coreutils extension
    printf 1; date
    sleep 1
    printf 1; date
    sleep 2
    printf 1; date
) &

(
    printf 2; date
    sleep 2
    printf 2; date
    sleep 1
    printf 2; date
) &

wait # for all processes to exit
```